# How can i export databse result in excel file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am exporting mysql database data to excel in laravel using maatwebsite. I am confusing why my file is downloading on click of button. Here is my coding. I get success response but failed to download file. I am trying to download excel file on click of button.

ExportOrders.php

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Exports;
    
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use DB;
    
class ExportOrders implements FromCollection
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    protected $fromDate, $toDate;

    public function __construct(String $fromDate, String $toDate) 
    {
        $this->fromDate = $fromDate;
        $this->toDate = $toDate;
    }
    
    public function collection()
    {
        //
        $orders = DB::table('orders')
                    ->join('table_users', 'table_users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
                    ->select('orders.*','table_users.name')
                    ->whereBetween('orders_date', [$this->fromDate, $this->toDate])
                    ->get();

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

controller

```php
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\ExportOrders;
    
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function export_to_excel(Request $request)
    {
        $from_date = $request->from_date;
        $to_date = $request->to_date;

        return Excel::download(new ExportOrders($from_date, $to_date), 'orders.xlsx');     
    }
}
```

blade code

```xml
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 20px;padding-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from_date" id="from_date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to_date" id="to_date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a type="submit" class="btn btn-info export_to_excel">Export to Excel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <a type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Export to PDF</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

script:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.export_to_excel', function() {
    var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
    var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/export-to-excel',
        data: {
            'from_date': from_date,
            'to_date': to_date
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'bottom-center');
            alertify.success(data.success);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The excel library you're using is not made to be used with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, the laravel excel library is not made to be used with javascript. If you want to choose between formats (excel, pdf), you could do it inside a single form.

You could add a third input (`<select>` or `<input type="radio">` for example) for the user to choose the format.

Or you could name your submit buttons.

Minimal route and form

```php
Route::post('export', [OrderController::class, 'export'])->name('export');
```

```xml
<form action="{{ route('export') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="date" id="from" name="from_date" onchange="$('#to').attr('min', this.value);" required>
    <input type="date" id="to" name="to_date" onchange="$('#from').attr('max', this.value);" required>
    <button type="submit" name="export_type" value="excel">Export to Excel</button>
    <button type="submit" name="export_type" value="pdf">Export to PDF</button>
</form>
```

```php
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function export(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->export_type === 'excel') {
            return Excel::download(new ExportOrders($request->from_date, $request->to_date), 'orders.xlsx');
        } elseif ($request->export_type === 'pdf') {
            // return pdf download
        } else {
            // throw/log error
        }
    }
}
```